# Telerik rad async file upload control is working well locally but not in server

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radupload

I am using  RadAsyncUpload control from Telerik to upload a file on the server. It is working well locally (on localhost) but not in the server. What did I miss?

(When I select a file to upload the dot becomes red instead of green)

Comment: Are you sure you are selecting a file with an allowed extension?

Comment: Yeah.The extension is allowed one only.It working well in my local system.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same behavior and it was a folder permissions issue.

Another symptom in this case, Chrome DevTools console was showing the following error when I attempt to upload a file:

- HTTP Error code is 500

There is a temp folder where RadAsyncUpload saves files temporarily. If you don't define the *TemporaryFolder* property on the RadAsyncUpload control, the default will be in your **App_Data\RadUploadTemp** folder. If **IIS_USERS** don't have write permissions to this folder, the upload can't save a file here. It will work on your localhost because you have write permissions to that folder. Here's how to give the permissions necessary.

1. Right click on the **App_Data\RadUploadTemp** folder on server and
   select proprties
2. Select Security tab
3. Click "Edit..." button
4. Under "Group or user names:", select IIS_USERS
5. Under "Permissions for IIS_USERS", check **Write** in the *Allow*
   column.

Note: This was IIS 7 on Windows 2008 R2 Server.

Answer (score 0):

The dot could become red either when the allowed file extension validation failed or when the file size exceeds the allowed one.

You can attach to the [OnClientValidationFailed](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-onclientvalidationfailed.html) and [OnClientFileUploadFailed](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-onclientfileuploadfailed.html) events and check what the exact error is and fix it.

The [Troubleshooting article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-troubleshooting.html) offers additional information about the different errors and how to solve them.